# PineScript - Mismatched input ')' expecting ':'

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4

New to PineScript, running this code but it gives me an error:

Script:

194 - if av_use

195 -     alert(message="e=" + broker + " b=long q="

196 -       + tostring(tradePositionSize)

197 -       + " s=" + pair

198 -       + " t=" + (av_limitOrder ? "limit fp=")

199 -       + " fsl=" + tostring(t_stop)

200 -       + " ftp=" + tostring(t_target)

201 -       + (av_gtdOrder != 0 and av_limitOrder ? gtdString : ""),

202 -       freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

Error:

Line 195: Mismatched input ')' expecting ':'.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables in brackets on line 198 make up only part of a ternary operator. Eg

```
(av_limitOrder ? "limit fp=")
```

It’s liking for something to follow as an “else” statement. Like this:

```
(av_limitOrder ? "limit fp=" : or something else when avlimitorder is false)
```

So we need a colon and another alternative variable within the brackets.

Cheers my friend